# Longitudinal sample with varying levels of non-response

Tags: survey, weights, survey-sampling, survey-weights, non-response

I'm using answers to a specific question from the General Social Survey ("do you feel rushed"?) to compare statistics over multiple years.

The answers are "Always" "Sometimes" "Never" and "Not applicable"

I'm using statistical weights to make sure the findings are representation:

```
general_social_survey_american_1982 = general_social_survey_american_1972_2016.query('YEAR == 1982')

total_weights_1982 = general_social_survey_american_1982['WTSS'].sum()

general_social_survey_american_1982 = general_social_survey_american_1982.groupby('RUSHED')['WTSS'].sum()

general_social_survey_american_1982 = (general_social_survey_american_1982 / total_weights_1982) * 100

general_social_survey_american_1982.index = general_social_survey_american_1982.index.map(general_social_survey_american_1972_2016_answers)
```

However, from 1996 to 2016, the percentage of "Not applicable" answers goes from almost 0% to 64%.

Because of that, the percentage of people that always, sometimes, or never rushed plummets dramatically.

I don't think using this approach allows for meaningful comparison over the years.

However, I was thinking of restricting the dataset only to participants who answers always, sometimes, or never, and then use weights to see what the percentages are:

```
general_social_survey_american_1972_2016 = general_social_survey_american_1972_2016[general_social_survey_american_1972_2016['RUSHED'].isin([1,2,3])]
```

In essence, the goal is to restrict the sample to only people who've answered the question and then compare the percentages.

So my question is: is this a sound approach? And if it is, what sum of weights should I use?  The total sum of weights (of the entire sample) or the sum of weights of the sample where only people who's answered the question are included?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!